# How does the tune package handles the mtry hyperparameter when applying step_dummy

Tags: r, hyperparameters, tidymodels, r-recipes

I'm defining the grid for a xgboost model with `grid_latin_hypercube()`. I understand that the `mtry` hyperparameter should be finalized either with the `finalize()` function or manually with the range parameter of `mtry()`.

Assuming that I have a dataframe with 10 variables: 1 id, 1 outcome, 7 numeric predictors and 1 categorical predictor with 10 equally frequent classes, and I run the following code:

```
folds <- vfold_cv(train_data)

xgb_spec <- boost_tree(
  trees = 2000,
  mtry = tune(),
) %>% 
  set_mode('regression') %>% 
  set_engine('xgboost')

xgb_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  finalize(mtry(), train_data),
  size = 5
)

xgb_rec <- recipe(outcome ~ ., data = train_data) %>% 
  update_role(id, new_role = 'id') %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

xgb_wflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(xgb_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(xgb_rec)

xgb_results <- tune_grid(
  xgb_wflow,
  resamples = folds,
  grid = xgb_grid,
  metrics = metrics_set(rmse),
  control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE, save_workflow = TRUE)
)
```

How does `tune` handle the new set of predictors (9 - 2 + 10 = 17) generated by the recipe, given that the grid hyperparameter was finalized with a dataframe with 10 variables?

Answer (score 1):

When finalizing manually, you'll have to run the `prep()`/`bake()` cycle (see [here](https://www.tmwr.org/dimensionality.html#recipe-functions)) to generate the preprocessed data.

Comment: When finalizing with `finalize()` should I use the prep/bake cycle?

Comment: If you are going to `finalize()` manually like this (rather than letting tune handle it for you) then yes.  In the example you have posted, you could skip finalizing manually and [instead pass `grid = 5` to `tune_grid()`](https://tune.tidymodels.org/reference/tune_grid.html#parameter-grids).